# Controlling distance between page number and text in terms of lines

Tags: page-numbering, documentclass-writing

According to the below requirement for my thesis, I would like to set the distance between page number and text in terms of number of lines.

> Page numbers must be at least two single spaces above or below the
>   nearest line of text.

Below is the class file I am working on.

**emu.cls:**

```
\LoadClass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{emu}[2019/06/03 My custom thesis class]

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % This is one of the ways of setting Times New Roman font.
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace} % double space in main text, otherwise single space for captions, header, footer.
\usepackage{geometry}\geometry{left=4cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm} % I think right margin is set implicitly.
\usepackage{graphicx} % to include figures.
\setlength{\parindent}{5ex} % "approximately five spaces" is mentioned in the manual. 5ex means xxxxx hopefully.
\usepackage{floatrow} % To center things. For example, no need to use \centering inside figure.
%\geometry{footskip=1cm} % Hmm. How to control the distance in terms of lines?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `%\geometry{footskip=1cm} % Hmm. How to control the distance in terms of lines?`

You could use, for example

```
footskip=2\normalbaselineskip
```

although it is a bit under specified whether you mean a "normal interline space" or the spacing after you have set up doublespace.

Starting from 12pt book class the default inter-line spaceing (`\baselineskip`) is 14.5pt so you can set `\footskip` to be whatever multiple of that that you want.

Comment: I mean the "single spacing" that is the spacing before setting double space. BTW, I could not find a description about `normalbaselineskip`. Is there an online free reference explaining stuff like `normalbaselikeskip`?

Comment: @Shibli certainly the latex documented source (`texdoc source2e`) not sure about other tutorials

Comment: I could not find where `\baselineskip` is 14.5pt for book class in the file you mentioned. Also, does `normalbaselineskip` change when line spacing is set to double spacing?

Comment: easiest way is to stick `\typeout{nornal baseline=\the\normalbaselineskip}`  or `\typeout{baseline=\the\baselineskip}`  at different pointsin your document